# how low in dataframe to find all elements of list

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I have a list:

```
elements = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

And a dataframe that has some or all of the elements of my list:

```
       mycol
0      a
1      x
2      y
3      e
4      b
5      c
6      o
7      l
8      s
9      d
10     g
```

I want to know how low I have to search on my df to find all of the elements of my list. In this case the answer would be `10` because it is until where I found all the elements of my list.

Thanks

Comment: This sounds like something there's unlikely to be a built-in function for. Just loop over the dataframe indexes. If the current df element is in the list, remove it from the list. When the list becomes empty, the current index is the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's worth considering [Barmar's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68947061/how-low-in-dataframe-to-find-all-elements-of-list/68947793#comment121849905_68947061). I couldn't get the fancier indexing answers to work with some bigger testing data, but Barmar's loop should be reliable:

> Just loop over the dataframe indexes. If the current df element is in the list, remove it from the list. When the list becomes empty, the current index is the answer.

```
def idxall(series, elements):
    for i, e in enumerate(series.to_numpy()): # faster than series.items()
        if e in elements:
            elements.remove(e)
            if not elements:
                return i + 1
    return np.nan
```

---

#### Timings

Given `df = pd.DataFrame({'mycol': np.random.choice(list(string.ascii_lowercase), size=1000)})`:

```
%timeit tdy_idxall(df.mycol, list(string.ascii_lowercase))
# 21.4 µs ± 7.44 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

```
%timeit henry_ecker_np_unique(df.mycol, list(string.ascii_lowercase))
# 379 µs ± 48.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

```
%timeit u12_forward_idxmax(df.mycol, list(string.ascii_lowercase)
# 538 µs ± 61.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

```
%timeit corralien_idxall(df.mycol, list(string.ascii_lowercase))
# 1.28 ms ± 243 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

---

#### Verification

- Using OP's sample:

  ```
  df = pd.DataFrame({'mycol': list('axyebcolsdg')})
  elements = list('abcd')

  idxall(df.mycol, elements)
  # 10
  ```
- Using Henry's sample #1 (mixed order and duplicates):

  ```
  df = pd.DataFrame({'mycol': list('dxcabcodsdg')})
  elements = list('abcd')

  idxall(df.mycol, elements)
  # 5
  ```
- Using Henry's sample #2 (not all elements found):

  ```
  df = pd.DataFrame({'mycol': list('dxcabcodsdg')})
  elements = list('abcz')

  idxall(df.mycol, elements)
  # nan
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Try `idxmax`:

```
>>> df['mycol'].isin(elements)[::-1].idxmax()
9
>>>
```

**Edit:**

For specifying all values in elements are in the dataframe, try:

```
x = df['mycol'].drop_duplicates().isin(elements).cumsum().eq(len(elements))
if x.any():
    print(x.idxmax())
else:
    print("Not all values are in the dataframe")
```

For your current dataframe:

```
9
```

For your dataframes where not all values are in the dataframe:

```
Not all values are in the dataframe
```

Comment: Doesn't this just find the last matching element value in `elements`? There doesn't seem to be any logic about finding "all of the elements of [the] list". The DataFrame `df = pd.DataFrame({'mycol': ['z', 'z', 'z', 'z', 'z', 'z', 'z', 'z', 'z', 'd', 'g']})` would also produce `9` even though we've only seen `d`.

Comment: @HenryEcker Edited my answer, please check it out

Comment: @HenryEcker Edited my answer.

Comment: @HenryEcker Edietd again

Comment: this doesn't work with some bigger data, e.g. `df = pd.DataFrame({'mycol': np.random.choice(list(string.ascii_lowercase), size=100000)}); elements = list(np.random.choice(list(string.ascii_lowercase), size=100))`

Answer (score 1):

We can use [`np.unique`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) with `return_index=True` in order to find the first instance of each unique value:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

elements = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'mycol': ['a', 'x', 'y', 'e', 'b', 'c', 'o', 'l', 's', 'd', 'g']
})

# Find the first location where each unique value is found
a, b = np.unique(df['mycol'], return_index=True)
# Compare unique values to values we're looking for
m = (a == np.array(elements)[:, None])
# If we have a location for all elements
if m.any(axis=1).all():
    # Find the highest index value
    max_index = b[m.any(axis=0)].max()
    # Offset index by one to match expected output
    print('All values found by', max_index + 1)
else:
    # We couldn't find all elements
    print('Not all elements found.')
```

```
All values found by 10
```

---

Example with mixed order and duplicates:

```
elements = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'mycol': ['d', 'x', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'o', 'd', 's', 'd', 'g']
})
```

```
   mycol
0      d
1      x
2      c
3      a
4      b
5      c
6      o
7      d
8      s
9      d
10     g
All values found by 5
```

Example with not all elements found:

```
elements = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'z']
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'mycol': ['d', 'x', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'o', 'd', 's', 'd', 'g']
})
```

```
   mycol
0      d
1      x
2      c
3      a
4      b
5      c
6      o
7      d
8      s
9      d
10     g
Not all elements found.  # (No z)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pd.CategoricalDtype` and use `set` to check if all elements are in the filtered dataframe:

```
def idxall(series, elements):
    out = series.astype(pd.CategoricalDtype(elements)) \
                .reset_index(drop=True) \
                .dropna().drop_duplicates()
    return out.index.max()+1 if not set(elements).difference(out) else np.nan
```

1. Your sample:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'mycol': list('axyebcolsdg')})
elements = list('abcd')
    
>>> idxall(df['mycol'], elements)
10
```

2. Henry's sample #1 (mixed order and duplicates):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'mycol': list('dxcabcodsdg')})
elements = list('abcd')

>>> idxall(df['mycol'], elements)
5
```

3. Henry's sample #2 (not all elements found):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'mycol': list('dxcabcodsdg')})
elements = list('abcz')

>>> idxall(df['mycol'], elements)
nan
```

Comment: note that this `Categorical` method only works if `elements` are all unique (though this is true with OP's provided sample)

Comment: @tdy. Yes but it's weird to have a list like ['a', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'd'], no? Except if the OP wants 2 instances of 'c' but it's not specified.

Comment: i dunno about weird. it just depends on the use case. maybe someone wants to determine how deep into the column until `['e','e','e','u']` are exhausted.